# Setting hotkey with variable

Tags: c#, variables

I am using this code below for hot key's and would like to use a variable for it but it does not let me:

```
private globalKeyboardHook Pvt = new globalKeyboardHook();
private globalKeyboardHook Group = new globalKeyboardHook();
string pvtHotkey = Properties.Settings.Default["pvtHotkey"].ToString();
Pvt.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F5);
Pvt.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(ghk_startPvt);
Group.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F6);
Group.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(ghk_startGroup);
```

I would like to do this:

```
string pvtHotkey = Properties.Settings.Default["pvtHotkey"].ToString();
Pvt.HookedKeys.Add(pvtHotkey);
Pvt.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(ghk_startPvt);
```

Error(s)
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(System.Windows.Forms.Keys)' has some invalid arguments

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(System.Windows.Forms.Keys)' has some invalid arguments

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of `Pvt.HookedKeys`?

Answer (score 0):

## The Problem

Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems that you are using the source file from the The Code Project article, [A Simple C# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook). 
If that is the case, then you are getting this error because the HookedKeys list was meant to contain Keys enums, not strings.

```
    public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();
```

## The Solution

You can fix this by converting the string into a Keys enum before you add it to the list.

### Include:

```
    using System.ComponentModel;
```

### Code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pvtHotkey = Properties.Settings.Default["pvtHotkey"].ToString();
        Keys converted = (Keys)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Keys)).ConvertFromString(pvtHotkey);
        Pvt.HookedKeys.Add(converted);
        Pvt.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(ghk_startPvt);
    }

    void ghk_startPvt(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Pressed!");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```